# Bar legend does not display values

Tags: version-9, legending

My `BarLegend` shows only zeros instead of right values and I cannot find the reason. I set following minimum and maximum:

```
MinC=-1.66423*10^-13; 
MaxC=9.39154*10^-13;
legend = BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {MinC, MaxC}}, LegendLayout -> "Column"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To the display precision, all of the numbers are zero; rescale.

```
MinC = -1.66423*10^-13;
MaxC = 9.39154*10^-13;
legend = BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {MinC, MaxC} 10^13}, 
  LegendLayout -> "Column", 
  LegendLabel -> "C * " <> ToString[10^"13", TraditionalForm]]
```

[image]